# Continuous integrable functions whose Fourier transform are not integrable.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Any suggestion for  necessary and sufficient condition for $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$? I mean  what proper condition on $f$   makes the following diagram complete?

$$ \hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \Longleftrightarrow (f=?)   $$

p.s. $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: One thing is clear from the inverse transform theorem: $f$ must be bounded.

Comment: $\hat{f}\rightarrow 0$ at $\pm\infty$ just because $f\in L^1$.